# catching change in spinbox - rtcltk

Tags: r, tcl, widget

I'm creating a spinbox in R using `rtcltk` with:

```
from <- tkwidget(leftFrame, type="spinbox", from=0, to=0.1, 
                         inc=0.001, textvariable=freqFrom,
                         command = function(){updatePlot()})
```

This works as intended (`updatePlot` is called) when I use the arrows of the spinbox, but does not work if I just type something in manually.

How do I catch the "value changed" event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it does not change in this case in case you type in an illegle value (like deleting the last digit), or if the update is time consuming then you would not want it to update between every keystroke when typing in a 3 or 4 digit number.

You can add an update button than calls updatePlot when clicked so that the user would type in the number and when they know they are finished would click the button.

If you really want the update to occur with every keystroke then you can use the tkbind function to call updatePlot (something like `tkbind(*spinbox*, "<Key>", updatePlot)` where *spinbox* is the variable pointing to the spinbox).

Comment: Thanks Greg, and say I want to just do it when the user presses ENTER after he/she changes the value? Is that possible?

Comment: @nico: Try `<Key-Return>` instead of `<Key>`.